# Is there a Daedalus wallet planned for mobile devices (Android and/or Apple)?

Tags: wallet, daedalus

Will I be able to delegate to a stake pool from my mobile phone with Daedalus?

Answer (score 6):

There is talk about Daedalus lite for mobiles. Charles mentioned it a couple of times. But I don't think it will be any time soon. It will be part of the next 5 year plan from IOG. But there will definitely be a Daedalus lite one day. For now it's Yoroi!

Comment: Definitely would be great to have a Daedalus lite for mobile devices. Nothing against Yoroi, haven't used it yet, so don't really have an opinion. Even if they were to make it a read-only mobile app where we can only check and see our ADA rewards and balance I'll be ok with that. But I'm sure it's easier said than done.

Comment: Yoroi may not be that intuitive but it does the job and its always with you on the mobile. I use both Daedalus and Yoroi. No complaints :). Oh don't you worry. When they do come up with Daedalus lite it will be awesome like everything else. "Quality" & "usability" are the main ingredients of anything built on Cardano! I have that much confidence by now.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use Daedalus on mobile because there is no mobile version. Daedalus is a "full node", i.e., it runs a cardano-node in the background, which maintains a complete copy of the blockchain. This is not intended to happen on mobile due to their limited resources. Mobile wallets like Yoroi work by connecting to a full node in the cloud.

WARNING: There have been apps claiming to be mobile versions of Daedalus pop up on some of the app stores. These are SCAMS! I've talked with people in the community that have had their ADA stolen because they trusted what appeared to be a legitimate Daedalus mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

No, Daedalus has no mobile version right now and there is no mobile version planned in the future. Daedalus is a full node wallet, this means the whole blockchain is downloaded to the device where the wallet is running. On mobile devices this would be impractical as there is usually not that much storage on those devices.

Comment: Thanks, I do know that currently there's no Daedalus wallet for mobile devices. But just wanted to know if it's planned in the future.

Comment: When you get enough rep, maybe you can convert this to a comment. Alternatively, maybe you can write a little more detail? I know it's a simple question with a simple answer, but it would be good for answers to be a bit more substantial than just 1 line.